# SQL Server 2014 Central Management Server

Tags: sql-server-2014

Can anyone tell list of all tasks I can do using CMS apart from Executing T-SQL code in multiple SQL Instances at same time.Thanks

Comment: here is a start for a reading: http://johnsterrett.com/?s=Central+Management+Server

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the T-SQL

1. Executing policy's across your environment, using different groups to evaluate different policy's. http://pietervanhove.azurewebsites.net/?p=1151
2. Working together with other dba's, this will enable you to list all the servers, and let your other dba's know that there is a new server. You will get an easy overview of everything installed in your environment.
3. Quickly open object explorer or logs from several servers and perform actions like restarting sql server service

In any environment, I do not see a reason to not use CMS. It just makes your life easier.